# Can't get a new tf.Operation to work in Python shell in Tensorflow

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I am trying to add a new integer Matrix Multiplication OP in tensorflow and I am not able to successfully register it as a tf operation so that it can be called as tf.intmatmul in python.

Steps I did :
1) Added a new REGISTER_OP - IntMatMul in the math_ops.cc file.

2) Added a new kernel implementation for this OP in the core/kernels path - int_matmul_op.cc and a corresponding header file - int_matmul_op.h

3) I added the dependency of the OP in the core/kernels/BUILD file. This will add the kernel linking for this OP.

4) Added the definition for this OP (as 'intmatmul') in the Python Wrapper file i.e python/ops/math_ops.py - This file calls the gen_math_ops.int_mat_mul

5) re-built from source using Bazel and re-installed Tensorflow using the pip package.

However when I try to use this OP as tf.intmatmul, I get an error saying the module is not defined. 
I am not sure now what I am missing here. Is there any linking that is missing?
Do I need to add any OP linking in the core/BUILD file as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPDATE:*

So this turned out to be more complicated than expected. These are the things that had to be taken into account:

- Apparently, in order for a function to be exposed as public API (that is, at `tf.` level), its name must be listed at the beginning of the module in its docstring preceded with `@@`. Take a look for example to [`math_ops.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py).
- The Kernel definition has to be absolutely correct in order to reflect an operation as an operation, even if you can still access it from the internal module (e.g. doing `from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops`).

--

As [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#use_the_op_in_python) indicate, the name of the operation, that must be registered with a CamelCase identifier in C++, is "translated" into snake_case in Python. Try `tf.int_mat_mul` instead.

As a side note, that tutorial provides additional guidance to implement custom operations without needing to recompile TensorFlow from source, loading it from a custom library instead.

Comment: I have given this a try as well. Doesn't work. I believe that tensorflow takes the name that is defined in the python wrapper. For ex in this case I have defined it as intmatmul in the python wrapper.

Comment: Where should I make this alias? In the python wrapper file?

Comment: I tried both these methods. Doesn't seem to work for me yet. The exact error is:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-82203134cb05> in <module>()
      1 mat1= tf.placeholder(tf.int16)
      2 mat2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int16)
----> 3 pro = tf.intmatmul(mat1,mat2)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'intmatmul'

Comment: Okay, two things. On the one hand, you may try to add `intmatmul` to the white list of exported symbols, adding `_allowed_symbols.extend(['intmatmul'])` before the call to `remove_undocumented` in [`tensorflow/python/__init__.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/__init__.py). Second, I've noted that in [`math_ops.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py) the functions of `gen_math_ops` are preceded by `_`; that's not your current error, but you may need to call `gen_math_ops._int_mat_mul` in you wrapper.

Comment: The Kernel definition has to be absolutely correct in order to reflect an operation as tf.operation. It will still reflect if I accessed it via math_ops.<operation>.
Way to debug : Check whether your build has the kernel library for your operation in this path : <path to python>/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/kernels/

Comment: @AyushiAgarwal I'm glad you solved it, thanks for accepting the answer even if I didn't quite solve your problem. I've updated the answer to better reflect the actual issue, feel free to edit it if you think it's wrong or could be improved.